# error in setTimeout function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new at angular and I do not understand why I am getting this error. I simply created a new project using `@angular/cli` command:

```
npm install -g @ angular / cli
ng new tutorial
```

and I modified the `component.ts` file

```
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'app';
 myselect:any;
 test:any= [{"id": "1", "nombre":"pedro" },{"id": "2", "nombre":"yeison" }];
 setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
}
```

and in the line of `setTimeout`, I'm getting this error.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(15,14): error TS1138: Parameter 
declaration expected. src/app/app.component.ts(15,42): error TS1068: 
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected. 
src/app/app.component.ts(15,48): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

What am I doing wrong or what is the problem?

Comment: In angular, do not expose executable code in class directly, just wrap it with a function or constructor. And if you want your code to be executed when component is created, it's recommended to write it in `OnInit` life hook.

Comment: @Pengyy if I put myfunction () {setTimeout ....}; myfunction () will work? what do you mean?

Comment: It's hard to explain in comment, I have given an example in below answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In angular, do not expose executable code in class directly, just wrap it with a function or in constructor. And if you want your code to be executed when component is created, it's recommended to write it in OnInit life hook.

See below code example:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'app';
  myselect:any;
  test:any= [{"id": "1", "nombre":"pedro" },{"id": "2", "nombre":"yeison" }];
  ngOnInit() {
    // by calling function here, you function will be executed when angular init your component
    this.timeoutFun();
  }
  // wrap code in a function
  timeoutFun() {
    setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 3000);
  }
}
```